# Nodehierarchy and access control...

Tags: 7, users, nodes

[This webcast](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode45) has a walkthru of NH; it includes the NH.Access module. I assume that he is using 6.x, as a lot of stuff is still very much beta'ish in 7.x, including NH.

I'm wondering if there is a module that gives me the ability to assing a permission to a node and its children.

My current setup is replacing a "Per-node" permission system, so the current Node Access grant is acceptable. I would like to progress into a "Per-Hierarchy" permission, so that a user can create children and maintain them without my intervention.

I just want to be sure I'm not missing a "related module" that's functional.

Comment: Any final solutions for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider the [Workbench Access](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_access) module: It is a hierarchy based approach to grants; it might be a much better match for your use case, and it can use a number of different hierarchy management tools, such as the Menu system, Taxonomy, etc.

Comment: I've actually seen the Workbench suite and just haven't had a chance to dig into it to see if it fits what we need more. I'll give it another look over.